# Getting rid of binary code from string before inserting row in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, utf-8

I am fetching tweets from Twitter and storing them in a database for future use. I am using `UTF-8` encoding in my driver, `utf8_mb4_bin` in my `VARCHAR` fields and `utf8mb4_general_ci`server collation. The problem with that is that when inserting a value in a `VARCHAR` field, if the text has any binary code then it will throw an exception since `VARCHAR` utf8 does not accept binary.

Here is an example, I am fetching the text [from here](https://twitter.com/TalOfficial/status/457536232957169664) and try inserting it in my database and I get the error:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\xB1\xF0\x9F...' for column 'fullTweet' at row 1
```

My guess is that the two emoticons are causing this. How do I get rid of them before inserting the `tweet text` in my database?

**Update:**

Looks like I can manually enter the emoticons. I run this query:

```
INSERT INTO `tweets`(`id`, `createdAt`, `screenName`, `fullTweet`, `editedTweet`) VALUES (450,"1994-12-19","john",_utf8mb4 x'F09F98B1',_utf8mb4 x'F09F98B1')
```

and this is what the row in the table looks like:

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you sure that everything is configured correctly for `utf8mb4` support? `character-set-server=utf8mb4` in server settings, `characterEncoding=UTF-8` in connection URL and correct collation for the field?

Comment: in the connection url at the end I add `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`. The "Server Connection Collation" is `utf8mb4_general_ci` and the field collation is `utf8mb4_bin` (I double checked them a million times).

Comment: And what is `character-set-server`?

Comment: `Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)` (I guess this is the one you are talking about).

Comment: What does `show variables like 'character_set_server'` show?

Comment: looks like that is `latin1` I guess I should change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove non ascii characters from tweet string before inserting.

`tweetStr = tweetStr.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `utf8mb4` support is still not configured correctly.

In order to use `utf8mb4` in your fields you need to do the following:

- Set `character-set-server=utf8mb4` in your `my.ini` or `my.cnf`. Only `character-set-server` really matters here, other settings don't.
- Add `characterEncoding=UTF-8` to connection URL:

  ```
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8
  ```
- Configure collation of the field

Comment: I still have the same problem. I literally set everything there was to `utf8mb4`. I went to `my.ini` and uncommented the line `character_set_server=utf8mb4`, I run the query you sent me before and it returns: `character_set_server=utf8mb4`. I altered the database collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. I altered the table's and each row's collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. The url is exactly how you wrote it. I really can't understand what is going on here.

Comment: What if you try to insert literal value `_utf8mb4 x'F09F98B1'` into that column manually?

Comment: Looks like that works (if I did it right). I will update my post with the query I run and how it is represented in the table.

Comment: I found what's wrong. Looks like I don't need to change the connection URL as well since I'm settting the `character-set-server`. Now it sorta works, it saves the text but with question marks instead of emoticons. That is good enough for me now.